# Tinymce filemanager not working at all + language not loading

Tags: php, javascript, html, tinymce

I have a problem with tinymce's filemanager. I tried to connect it, but someting went wrong. When I select some text and I try to create a link to it. When I click the "chain" icon and then the "browse" button, the filemanager loads but it doesn't work. I can't do anything and also the there is no language. Every label is like: `{#filelist.filename}`. Can you give me some advice.

Here is my init code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    width: "1000",
    height: "550",
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "BODY,DESCRIPTION,LONG_DESCRIPTION, LONG_DESCRIPTION1, LONG_DESCRIPTION2, LONG_DESCRIPTION3, LONG_DESCRIPTION4, LONG_DESCRIPTION5",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "imagemanager,filemanager,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code,insertdate,inserttime,preview",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "forecolor,backcolor,|,tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    language: "en",
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
        {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
        {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
        {title : 'Table styles'},
        {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
    ]
});
```

I am not sure if you need it but here is the code in the config.php file within the filemanager's 
folder:

```
$mcFileManagerConfig['general.theme'] = "fm";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.user_friendly_paths'] = true;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.tools'] = "imagemanager,createdir,createdoc,refresh,zip,upload,edit,rename,cut,copy,paste,delete,selectall,unselectall,view,download,insert,addfavorite,removefavorite";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.disabled_tools'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.error_log'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.language'] = "ru"; // en, sv, ru
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.plugins'] = "History,Favorites"; // comma seperated
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.demo'] = false;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.debug'] = false;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.encrypt_paths'] = true;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.remember_last_path'] = false;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.allow_override'] = "*";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['general.allow_export'] = "demo,tools,disabled_tools,debug";

    // Preview options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.wwwroot'] = ''; // absolute or relative from this script path (c:/Inetpub/wwwroot).
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.urlprefix'] = "{proto}://{host}/"; // domain name
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.urlsuffix'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.exclude_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.extensions'] = "*";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.allow_export'] = "urlprefix,urlsuffix";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['preview.allow_override'] = "*";

    // General file system options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem'] = "Moxiecode_LocalFileImpl";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.path'] = '../../../../../../uploads/artanesmining/tinymcefiles/';//'../../../../upload-files/'; // absolute or relative from this script path.
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.rootpath'] = '../../../../../../uploads/artanesmining/tinymcefiles/';//'../../../../upload-files/'; // absolute or relative from this script path.
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.datefmt'] = "Y-m-d H:i";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.include_directory_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.exclude_directory_pattern'] = '/^mcith$/i';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.invalid_directory_name_msg'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.exclude_file_pattern'] = '/^\.|mcic_/i';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.invalid_file_name_msg'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.extensions'] = "gif,jpg,htm,html,pdf,zip,txt,php,png,swf,dcr,mov,qt,ram,rm,avi,mp3,mpg,mpeg,asf,flv,doc,pdf,xls,xslx,docx";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.file_templates'] = '${rootpath}/templates/document.htm,${rootpath}/templates/another_document.htm';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.directory_templates'] = '${rootpath}/templates/directory,${rootpath}/templates/another_directory';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.readable'] = true;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.writable'] = true;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.delete_recursive'] = true;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.force_directory_template'] = false;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.clean_names'] = true;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.allow_export'] = "extensions,readable,writable,file_templates,directory_templates,force_directory_template,clean_names";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Upload options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.maxsize'] = "20MB";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.overwrite'] = false;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.exclude_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.invalid_file_name_msg'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.extensions'] = "gif,jpg,mp3,png,pdf,zip,swf,doc,pdf,xls,xslx,docx";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.multiple_upload'] = true;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.chunk_size'] = '1mb';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.allow_export'] = "maxsize,multiple_upload,chunk_size,overwrite,extensions";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['upload.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Download options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['download.include_file_pattern'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['download.exclude_file_pattern'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['download.extensions'] = "gif,jpg,htm,html,mp3,pdf,txt,zip";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['download.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Create document options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdoc.fields'] = "Document title=title";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdoc.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdoc.exclude_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdoc.invalid_file_name_msg'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdoc.allow_export'] = "fields";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdoc.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Create directory options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdir.include_directory_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdir.exclude_directory_pattern'] = '/[^a-z0-9_\.]/';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdir.invalid_directory_name_msg'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['createdir.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Rename options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['rename.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['rename.exclude_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['rename.invalid_file_name_msg'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['rename.include_directory_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['rename.exclude_directory_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['rename.invalid_directory_name_msg'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['rename.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Edit file options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['edit.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['edit.exclude_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['edit.extensions'] = "html,htm,txt";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['edit.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Zip file(s) options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['zip.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['zip.exclude_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['zip.extensions'] = "*";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['zip.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Unzip file(s) file options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['unzip.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['unzip.exclude_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['unzip.extensions'] = "*";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['unzip.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Authenication
    $mcFileManagerConfig['authenticator'] = "BaseAuthenticator";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['authenticator.login_page'] = "login_session_auth.php";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['authenticator.allow_override'] = "*";

    // SessionAuthenticator
    $mcFileManagerConfig['SessionAuthenticator.logged_in_key'] = "isLoggedIn";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['SessionAuthenticator.groups_key'] = "groups";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['SessionAuthenticator.user_key'] = "user";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['SessionAuthenticator.path_key'] = "mc_path";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['SessionAuthenticator.rootpath_key'] = "mc_rootpath";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['SessionAuthenticator.config_prefix'] = "filemanager";

    // ExternalAuthenticator config
    $mcFileManagerConfig['ExternalAuthenticator.external_auth_url'] = "auth_example.jsp";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['ExternalAuthenticator.secret_key'] = "someSecretKey";

    // Local filesystem options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.local.access_file_name'] = "mc_access";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.local.allow_override'] = "access_file_name";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.local.file_mask'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.local.directory_mask'] = "";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Stream options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['stream.mimefile'] = "mime.types";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['stream.include_file_pattern'] = '';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['stream.exclude_file_pattern'] = '/\.php$|\.shtm$/i';
    $mcFileManagerConfig['stream.extensions'] = "*";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['stream.allow_override'] = "*";

    // Logging options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['log.enabled'] = false;
    $mcFileManagerConfig['log.level'] = "error"; // debug, warn, error
    $mcFileManagerConfig['log.path'] = "logs";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['log.filename'] = "{level}.log";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['log.format'] = "[{time}] [{level}] {message}";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['log.max_size'] = "100k";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['log.max_files'] = "10";

    // Image manager options
    $mcFileManagerConfig['imagemanager.urlprefix'] = "../../../imagemanager/?type=im";  // need to add "imagemanager" button to tools as well.
    $mcFileManagerConfig['imagemanager.allow_override'] = "*";
    $mcFileManagerConfig['imagemanager.allow_export'] = "urlprefix";
```

I hope that this is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you add path to tiny on your page ? :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="YOUT_PATH/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Try add to  filemanager`s folder config.php

```
ini_set('display_errors',0); // may be bug with languages
```

Chage path to upload files

```
$mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].PATH_UPLOAD_FOLDER
$mcFileManagerConfig['filesystem.rootpath'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].PATH_UPLOAD_FOLDER
```