# TinyMCE FileManager and ImageManager Stopped Working After PHP 5.4 Upgrade

Tags: php, tinymce, datalife-engine

I recently upgraded a server for my client, and the new server runs PHP 5.4.4 instead of 5.3.x as the old one did.

Lots of things changed and I had to go around and fix htmlspecialchars(), session_register() and other problems, but one problem remains a complete mystery:

Now when I click the image manager in TinyMCE, the language pack doesn't seem to work at all, it shows labels like: `{#common.filter}`, `{#view.thumbnail}` etc. The language is Russian and the system is integrated with a Russian CMS called DataLife Engine. Other functions in TinyMCE, like regular text editing, work fine.

I looked at this similar question: [Tinymce filemanager not working at all + language not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741188/tinymce-filemanager-not-working-at-all-language-not-loading)
but it doesn't seem to be quite the same issue since it worked and no changes were made in the configuration of TinyMCE, and the paths on the website and even the whole server are exactly the same. Only the PHP configuration changed.

Is there some kind of well-known issue upon 5.4 upgrade? Please let me know what other information is necessary.

P.S. Upgrading TinyMCE is not an option.

Comment: Because of the nature of the problem, unfortunately I could not wait more time and downgraded PHP, which solved the problem. If anyone still has the answer on how to make it work with PHP 5.4, it would be very interesting to read it!

Comment: have you solved problem with php 5.4 version. I'm experience the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, still using PHP 5.3.x for the website in question.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem under php5.4, after tracing using firebug i found the errors below:

**Strict Standards**:  Declaration of Moxiecode_LocalFileImpl::copyTo() should be compatible with Moxiecode_BaseFile::copyTo($dest) in 
**../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/classes/FileSystems/LocalFileImpl.php** on line **829**

**Strict Standards**:  Declaration of Moxiecode_LocalFileImpl::renameTo() should be compatible with Moxiecode_BaseFile::renameTo($dest) in 
**../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/classes/FileSystems/LocalFileImpl.php** on line **829**

**Strict Standards**:  Declaration of Moxiecode_HistoryPlugin::onInsertFile() should be compatible with Moxiecode_ManagerPlugin::onInsertFile(&$man, &$file) in
 **../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/plugins/History/History.php** on line **79**

Try the fix below:

-Go to tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/classes/FileSystems|**BaseFile.php**

1- on line 154 change "**copyTo($dest)**" to "**copyTo(&$dest)**"

2- on line 215 change "**renameTo($dest)**" to "**renameTo(&$dest)**"

-Go to tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/classes|**ManagerPlugin.php**

1- on line 225 change "**onInsertFile(&$man, &$file)**" to "**onInsertFile(&$man, $file)**"

Comment: I also had to edit  tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/classes/FileSystems/FileFilter.php and change line 22 from this: function accept($file) { to this:
function accept(&$file) {

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know php 5.4 only supported by DLE 9.8 UTF-8 and DLE 10.0 so if you use one of those versions then the problem you have seems to be related to jQuery popup more than script issue but I can be easily wrong.